# Point inside a triangle is always closer to the side of a triangle rather than to vertices of the triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Given a triangle and a point inside the triangle, is it always the case that the point is closer (or equal distance to) one of the sides of the triangle rather than to any of the vertices of the triangle?

i.e. Given triangle $ABC$ and point $P$ inside $\triangle ABC$, prove:

$$\min\limits_{V \in {A, B, C}} d(A,V) \geq \min\limits_{E \in {AB, BC, CA}} d(A, E)$$

It may be important to note that the side of the triangle is valid to measure the distance to, if the line connecting P and the side is also inside the triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, drop a perpendicular to each side.  It should be obvious that the shortest of these is the shortest distance to any point on that side (including the vertices).

If the triangle is obtuse (thanks for pointing out this case!), then (at most) one perpendicular will be outside the triangle.  We can eliminate this side from consideration because the distance from $P$ to the other side containing the shared vertex will be shorter than the distance to the vertex.

Comment: It is not obvious considering the last paragraph and obtuse triangles.

Answer (score 2):

For some point $P$ in the triangle, the line connecting that point to the closest point on any side will be perpendicular to that side. If we let this closest point on a side be $D$, and let $A$ be the closest vertex to $P$, then APD will be a right-triangle with AP as its hypotenuse.

The length of AD is the shortest distance to a side, the length of AP is the shortest distance to a vertex, and we know that AD must be shorter than AP because AP is the hypotenuse, therefore it is true that a point can always be found on a side which is closer to $P$ than any vertex.

Comment: True for acute triangles, but with the last paragraph constraint and obtuse triangles I'm not sure it is that straightforward.

Comment: @Daniyar Ah I see yes, for obtuse the perpendicular line to one side can leave the triangle. However, I think at most only one perpendicular can leave the triangle, and for the line between $P$ and any vertex, two right-triangles can be constructed out of two of the three perpendiculars. That would mean there is always at least one valid right-triangle you can use to prove that there is a closer side.

Comment: but could the side with the valid right-triangle could be further than the vertex opposite to that side?

Comment: @Daniyar if $A$ is the closest vertex to $P$, then at least one of the perpendiculars which connect $P$ to side $AB$ and $P$ to side $AC$ will remain inside the triangle, and therefore form a valid right-triangle, with $AP$ as the hypotenuse, meaning that $P$ must still be closer to one of $AB$ and $AC$ than it is to $A$.